# Get all unique target sum compositions for a given array of numbers

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

I'm dealing with a particularly nasty variant of the subset sum problem.

Consider this example. Let's say we have several warehouses with different quantities of some item. For instance:

- *London - 1 item*
- *Liverpool - 2 items*
- *Newcastle - 50 items*
- *Manchester - 70 items*

Let's say we also have a delivery order for 100 items and we want to create all possible combinations that can satisfy this order, like this:

- *Manchester (70) + Newcastle (30)*
- *Newcastle (50) + Manchester (50)*
- *London (1) + Newcastle (50) + Manchester (49)*
- *London (1) + Manchester (70) + Newcastle (29)*
- *Liverpool (2) + Newcastle (50) + Manchester (48)*
- *Liverpool (2) + Manchester (70) + Newcastle (28)*
- *London (1) + Liverpool (2) + Newcastle (50) + Manchester (47)*
- *London (1) + Liverpool (2) + Manchester (70) + Newcastle (27)*

I want to write an algorithm that can produce such output for an arbitrary amount of warehouses and stocks.

Some caveats:

- If we take the whole stock from two warehouses, the order does not matter. For example, *London (1) + Liverpool (2) + Newcastle (50) + Manchester (47)* is equivalent to *Liverpool (2) + London (1) + Newcastle (50) + Manchester (47)* and we should only return one variant (does not matter which one)
- On the other hand, if we only take some part of the stock, the order matters. For example, *London (1) + Liverpool (2) + Newcastle (50) + Manchester (47)* is NOT equivalent to *Liverpool (2) + London (1) + Manchester (70) + Newcastle (27)* and we should return both variants
- The number of warehouses (and variants) can be very high, so I cannot allocate any additional memory for, say, hash sets

With this amount of caveats I'm not even sure if this is a variant of the subset sum problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't explicilty state this but it looks like you must pick up all available product at each warehouse you visit up to their inventory or your capacity. I.e. Manchester 50, London 50 is not legal. Correct?

Comment: `On the other hand` part is not clear.

Comment: OP seems to want combinations and not permutations of those possibilities. And yes, taking part of the quantity is also ok. So it is similar to fractional knapsack.

Comment: @nice_dev But you only take part at the end.

Comment: @nice_dev In fractional knapsack you can break lots of items.  In this, you can only take part of one.  That makes this nicer for DP approaches.

Comment: @btilly I believe we could  break more than 1 item since OP hasn't mentioned it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that the truck picks up as much as it can everywhere (so the only possible partial load is at the last place it visits), the following code should work:

```
def loads (load_size, warehouse_capacity):
    warehouses = list(warehouse_capacity.keys())

    subset_sums = {0: None}
    for i in range(len(warehouses)):
        capacity = warehouse_capacity[warehouses[i]]
        for prev_sum in list(subset_sums.keys()):
            if prev_sum + capacity <= load_size:
                if prev_sum + capacity not in subset_sums:
                    subset_sums[prev_sum + capacity] = [i]
                else:
                    subset_sums[prev_sum + capacity].append(i)

    def comb_sums (target, partial_comb):
        if target == 0:
            yield partial_comb
        else:
            for i in subset_sums[target]:
                if i not in partial_comb:
                    capacity = warehouse_capacity[warehouses[i]]
                    partial_comb[i] = capacity
                    for comb in comb_sums(target - capacity, partial_comb):
                        yield comb
                    partial_comb.pop(i)

    for target in subset_sums.keys():
        if target == load_size:
            for comb in comb_sums(load_size, {}):
                yield dict([(warehouses[i], c) for i, c in comb.items()])
        else:
            for j in range(len(warehouses)):
                if load_size < target + warehouse_capacity[warehouses[j]]:
                    for comb in comb_sums(target, {j: load_size-target}):
                        yield dict([(warehouses[i], c) for i, c in comb.items()])

for comb in loads(100, {'London': 1, 'Liverpool': 2, 'Newcastle': 50, 'Manchester': 70}):
    print(comb)
```